# linux machine not visible to pc or macs at home

Tags: networking

Setup Linux 12.10 machine from scratch, it can connect to the internet no problem. However I cannot see the linux machine from my PC or mac, is there something else I need to do ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should check if you can connect to your own LAN. If you can't connect to your LAN you should check the media in use and if your system needs additional drivers.

Moreover you should check if your Ubuntu system has received an IP address, a gateway address and a DNS server address. You can check this using either a graphical tool or by using the `ifconfig`  command in a terminal.

Comment: Hi, yes they have an ipaddress and actually Ive realized I can ping to the linux machine from mac and vice versa. But I want to be able to ping via name, trouble is the ipaddress can change its ipaddress allocated by router so just editing /etc/hots is not a good solution. Also want to be able to ssh and ftp to my linux machine from my mac, I want to see linux drive from mac

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure that the virtual Network interface is Bridged and it has an IP in same network as your PC/MAC.
- Also, I think you will need to install SAMBA protocols for the Linux machine to be visible to the PC networks and computers.